# Appledoc Exception: At least one directory or file name path is required

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, appledoc

```
Cho-Yeung-Lam:gogopiao_v2 apple$ appledoc -o ./doc --project-name gogopiao_v2
```

as I type the command above, error occur:

At least one directory or file name path is required, use '`appledoc --help`'

**gogopiao_v2** is the root directory of my project. Hope someone could help me with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the path where appledoc is supposed to search for your source file documentation. Also, specifying the project company is mandatory.

After listing the OPTIONS you have to tell appledoc the directory of your source files.

```
appledoc -o ./doc --project-name gogopiao_v2 --project-company YourCompany ./
```